# Lost Drop Down Menu After Using HTML INCLUDE

Tags: html, css, include

I wanted to pull my main menu and sub menu from a single file so I used the INCLUDE code found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

After the change, my drop down menus stopped showing up when you hover over the MAIN MENU. Clearly there is a disconnect but I'm not sure what's happening. It's been a while since I've coded. I would appreciate some assistance

What the main menu should look like: http://torontooutdoorsoccer.com/contact.html

What it looks like after the changes: http://torontooutdoorsoccer.com

Comment: The menu looks the same in both links.

Comment: I think that it's not a good practice to do that. I've never seen someone use that. It's best just to put the main and sub menus code into the code for the desired html page. Save the including for ReactJS.

Comment: @jmargolisvt hover over the MAIN menu you'll see drop down menus on the first link. The second one you don't see them

Comment: @LukaMiljković i'm trying to avoid having to update the menus on each page individually.